# How to find last iteration in below for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following Oracle query. I am trying to find last index in the iteration, In other words, I want to print the result only in last step. But I have no success

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  str VARCHAR2(100) := 'a,c,v,b';
  V_CMP_MUMBER VARCHAR2(20);
   V_CMP_MUMBERS VARCHAR2(200);
  BEGIN
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
   FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, ',')+1
   )
   LOOP
   select cn INTO V_CMP_MUMBER from VP where NAME=i.l;
   V_CMP_MUMBERS := V_CMP_MUMBERS || ',' || v_cmp_mumber;
     dbms_output.put_line(REGEXP_REPLACE(V_CMP_MUMBERS,'^,', '' ));
    
  END LOOP;
 END;
  /
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a loop and do it all in a single SQL query:

```sql
DECLARE
  str VARCHAR2(100) := 'a,c,v,b';
  V_CMP_MUMBERS VARCHAR2(200);
  v_count       PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*),
         LISTAGG(cn, ',')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY INSTR(','||str||',', ','||name||','))
  INTO   v_count,
         V_CMP_MUMBERS
  FROM   VP
  WHERE  INSTR(','||str||',', ','||name||',') > 0;

  dbms_output.put_line('Number of rows matched: ' || v_count);
  dbms_output.put_line('Matches: ' || V_CMP_MUMBERS);
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE vp (name, cn) AS
SELECT 'a', 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'ccc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'v', 'vvv' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Number of rows matched: 4
> Matches: aaa,ccc,vvv,bbb
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ed149bd697583541dc98226b9a438b1)*

Answer (score 1):

Move `dbms_output.put_line` call out of the loop.

For my sample table:

```
SQL> select * from vp;

        CN N
---------- -
       100 a
       200 b
       300 c
       400 v

SQL>
```

result is then

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    str            VARCHAR2(100) := 'a,c,v,b';
  3    V_CMP_MUMBER   VARCHAR2(20);
  4    V_CMP_MUMBERS  VARCHAR2(200);
  5    l_last_index   number := 0;
  6  BEGIN
  7    FOR i IN
  8      (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
  9       FROM dual
 10       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, ',')+1
 11      )
 12    LOOP
 13      l_last_index := l_last_index + 1;
 14      select cn INTO V_CMP_MUMBER from VP where NAME=i.l;
 15      V_CMP_MUMBERS := V_CMP_MUMBERS || ',' || v_cmp_mumber;
 16    END LOOP;
 17    dbms_output.put_line('Last index = ' || l_last_index);
 18    dbms_output.put_line(REGEXP_REPLACE(V_CMP_MUMBERS,'^,', '' ));
 19  END;
 20  /
Last index = 4
100,300,400,200

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I thought code is in outside loop. My bad. Thanks for your note

Comment: I have a question here, can we find index here in loop ?

Comment: Yes; add another local variable (I named it L_LAST_INDEX); have a look at edited code.